# Create an URL that contains informations to center the map present on the site linked

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I need to create an URL that leads to a page that contains a map, but this map must be centered depending on the link itself.

For example, I need that the link *"my home"* brings to the page *"map.html"* where the contained map shows the position of my home, and another link *"my office"*  that brings to the same page *"map.html"* with the map that this time shows the position of my office.

Is this possible? I didn't find any information about that on the Google manual.

If this is not possible via google API, which kind of solution do you suggest?

---

I cannot use the answering button, so I post my solution here:

The link can be created with query strings, as suggested. I prefered to use PHP.

> map.php?lat=30&long=20

Inside the page you have just to insert, between the Google Maps code:

```
<?php
                if (empty($_GET["lat"]) || (empty($_GET["long"])))
                {
                    echo "var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.49558,14.122316);"
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(" . $_GET["lat"] . "," . $_GET["long"] . ");"
                }
?>
```

So, if the query strings are not present, you obtain the HTML with generic coordinate.
Easy and fast.
Thanks to all.

Comment: [Example of link to markers in map by "id"](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_linktomarker.html?id=Marker%20Two), ported to v3 from [Mike Williams' Google Maps API v2 tutorial](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/linktothis.htm)

Comment: @geocodezip: Thanks for the links. I used a different approach, but this is usefull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of solution? Google Maps API

How? You should read well the Google Maps API documentation which is extensive and packed with code samples.

Now, in a nutshell, your map needs to know some basic information which you MUST provide, that information is geographical location which comes in latitudes and longitudes. Then you must provide this information to your html page. How? It's up to you...querystrings are a good fit for this scenario. Then, parse this information using javascript, create the Google Maps Location object, add a pointer using this location and center the map using this pointer. Simple.  Again, for more information read the documentation and then come back and ask a more specific question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was unfamiliar with query strings. I used a solution made by Query strings and PHP. Just to complete my question, I'll write my solution as soon as possible.